# Why is my custom test not being launched by PHPUnit?

Tags: phpunit

As described in the [PHPUnit doc](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.1/extending-phpunit.html#implement-phpunit-framework-test), you can implement `PHPUnit\Framework\Test` to write custom tests.

Sound great, but how can I launch those tests as part of my testsuite?

Given the following test directory:

```
+tests/
   |- NormalTestExtendingTestCaseTest.php
   |- CustomTestImplementingTest.php
phpunit.xml
```

And my phpunit.xml file:

```
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/6.3/phpunit.xsd"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="My Test Suite">
            <directory>./tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Only NormalTestExtendingTestCaseTest.php is executed by PHPUnit.

---

CustomTestImplementingTest.php

```
<?php
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class CustomTestImplementingTest implements PHPUnit\Framework\Test
{

    public function count()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public function run(PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult $result = null)
    {
        if ($result === null) {
            $result = new PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult;
        }

        $result->startTest($this);
        // do something
        $result->endTest($this, $stopTime);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem:

1. The custom test class should implement a `suite()` method so PHPUnit run the resulting TestSuite (with our test(s))
2. The test class should declare a getter method `getName()` (even if it's not declared in the interface `PHPUnit\Framework\Test` or an exception is thrown at execution. Moreover, the name should not be null or an other exception is throw at execution.

So the final class is

```
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite;
use SebastianBergmann\Timer\Timer;
use PHPUnit\Framework\Test;

class CustomTestImplementingTest implements Test {

    protected $name = '';

    /**
     * This method create a TestSuite for this Test
     *
     * @return TestSuite
     * @throws ReflectionException
     */
    public static function suite() {
        $classname = (new \ReflectionClass(static::class))->getShortName();
        $suite = new TestSuite();
        $suite->setName($classname);
        $suite->addTest(new static());
        return $suite;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $name
     */
    public function setName($name): void {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function count() {
        return 1;
    }

    public function run(TestResult $result = null): TestResult {
        if ($result === null) {
            $result = new PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult;
        }
        Timer::start();
        $stopTime = null;
        $result->startTest($this);

        try {
            // do something
        } catch (PHPUnit\Framework\AssertionFailedError $e) {
            $result->addFailure($this, $e, $stopTime);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $result->addError($this, $e, $stopTime);
        } finally {
            $stopTime = Timer::stop();
        }

        $result->endTest($this, $stopTime);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that your classes has the correct inheritance, the correct name methods (starting with 'test'), and the correct namespace.

You maybe have to run the composer dump-autoload.

Comment: Well, as my class implement `Test` instead of `TestCase`, I expect the `run` method to be called not the `test...()` methods.